# Struggling with the reasoning of why this is so - proofs

Tags: formal-proofs

I'm just starting out learning how to proof and I am struggling to grasp the basics yet. I'm writing out examples and trying to understand them but I am still not seeing how I should go about doing my own.

This is one example, that I've spent much of today working on:

The sum of an even number and and odd number is odd.

Firstly, I translated this into mathematical language:

$\forall$ x ∈ Z ∃ m ∈ is even ∃ Z ∧ x is odd → 
m + n  = x

Then I've attempted to solve it by using a direct proof, P->Q (I need to prove P, Q is an assumption), however I've got lost here.

I think I need to prove that P (the sum is odd) and manipulate the equation to show that this will always be the case. I'm really lost.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. To start with, how do you define an even number or an even number?

Comment: You should see how to place math equations in your text using MathJax - it is not hard.  I would give a link but you could just google it. It would be good to see your attempt at putting this in math language so we can know whether and where you have gotten lost.

Comment: Try proving it by reductio ad absurdum. Suppose that the sum is odd, and you should be able to arrive to a statement that contradicts your hypotheses.

Comment: In my proof I'm calling the m divisible by 2, yes then its even, no then odd.

Comment: Hint: you can represent an even number as $2k$ for some integer $k$, and an odd number as $2n+1$ for some integer $n$. Can you see what follows?

Comment: For formatting, try enclosing expressions in dollar signs: `$x+y$` gives $x+y$. Here is a more detailed [formatting guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thomas Bladt - yes, is that universal? Like an accepted? because that was the solution I came across on the web but there was no reasoning offered.

Comment: The main thing you need are formal *definitions* of "even" and "odd." If you're not sure what counts as a formal definition, maybe that's the real question.

Comment: @Jenny The proof is valid because it works for any two _arbitrary_ numbers. You could take any even number there is, say, $20$, and write it as mentioned before: $20 = 2 \cdot 10$. Similarly, you could take any odd number, say, $17$, and write it as mentioned before: $17=(2 \cdot 8) + 1$. (In this example, $20+17=37$, which is an odd number.) So you will have shown that the statement is true for _every_ sum of an odd and an even number. A little advice: when writing proofs, always show that the statement holds for _all_ possible cases, not just a particular one.

Comment: Even = divisible by 2 = "$x = 2k$ for some integer $k$" is a n acceptable definition.  And odd = not even = $y=2j$ for any integer $j$. Is acceptable.  But we have to prove that "not even" = "$y = 2j + 1$ for some integer $j$".

Comment: Can you accept the "division principal"  That for any number $m$ and $b$ there are unique integers $q,r$ so that $m = qb + r; 0 \le r < b$.  If we do this for $b=2$. That means all integers can be written as $x = 2q$ or $x = 2q + 1$.  If $x=2q$ it is, by definition even.  If $x = 2q + 1$ it is, by definition, not even and therefore, by definition, odd.  So all even numbers are $2k$ for some integer $k$ and all odd are $2k + 1$ for some integer $k$.  ... Of courese we have to prove the division principal...

Answer (score 1):

One of the basic tactics for proofs it to write givens at the top of the paper and what you're trying to prove at the bottom. Then work towards each other: sometimes it will be easier to work your way down, and other times it will be easier to work backwards and work your way up. Once you've connected the top and bottom, you're done.

Givens include the conditions (that is, the "if" part of an "if then" statement), axioms, definitions, and applicable theorems. Givens can also take other forms, for instance if you're asked to prove "For all X, Y is true", it's given that you're dealing with X.

So here, your first givens are:

m is even
n is odd

The next step is to go through all the key words and find their definitions. The two key words are "even" and "odd". So write down what the definitions of "even" and "odd" are. Usual definitions are:

there is i such that 2i = m
there is j such that 2j+1 = n

So now you can take the expression m+n and substitute in: m+n = (2i)+(2j+1)

If you've written what you're supposed to prove at the bottom, you should have "(m+n) is odd". You can use the definitions above to say that this is equivalent to "there is k such that 2k+1 = m+n". You can then write that right above your bottom statement.

So now you just have to connect  m+n = (2i)+(2j+1) to m+n = 2k+1.

So:

Write down what you're told at the top (conditions, etc.)
 Write down what you're supposed to prove at the bottom
If you can think of any theorems that apply, write those down at the top, just below what you're told
Search for key words in what you've written down so far
Find the definitions for key words, and write them at the top, just below any theorems
Work down from the top and up from the bottom until they meet